# How to only return certain properties of the class as JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

I am using drop wizard which uses Jackson for returning classes as JSON.

How can I return only certain properties in a class as JSON rather than returning all the properties.

For example the User POJO

```
public class User {
  private int id;
  private String username;
  private String password
  //getter setters
}
```

and the `signin` path:

```
@GET
@Path("/signin")
public User signin(@Auth User user) {
    return user;
}
```

returns `{"password":null,"id":0,"username":"foobar"}` How can I only return `{"username":"foobar"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can annotate the field or getter/setter with

```
@JsonIgnore
```

Or annotate the class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"password", "id"})
```